# Разница между сервисом и классом

Tags: c#

С коллегой возникла дискуссия что считать сервисом, а что классом. После непродолжительной размышления пришли к выводу, что скорее всего сервис - это класс, который имеет зависимости и служит для повторяющихся задач, но нам самим такая формулировка не нравится, так как во многом подходит и обычным статическим классам-помощникам.

В чём принципиальная разница между сервисом и классом? По каким признакам можно сказать, что это уже не класс, а сервис? По каким признакам можно сказать, что это не сервис, а класс?

Comment: Что имеете ввиду под сервисом?

Comment: Под сервисом имеются ввиду классы (взять хотя бы те-же Microsoft'овские из BCL) в названии которых имеется `Service`.

Comment: Какой например?

Comment: Обычно сервисом называют класс, который используется на всех уровнях приложения. Например сервис логирования, сервис аутентификации, сервис. Еще сервисом могут называть фасад какой то функциональности, типа сервис печати, сервис отправки писем. Сервисом могут называть запущенный отдельно код со своим ограниченным контекстом, типа Discovery Service, или сервис обмена валют. Это, как я думаю, широкое понятие. А класс - это весьма конкретное. Вы всегда можете понять, является ли обсуждаемый предмет классом. Но не всегда ясно, является ли он методом.

Comment: К примеру [WebService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webservice?view=netframework-4.7.2), но это не суть важно. Каким образом можно определить, что класс должен быть сервисом? Т.е. как можно сформулировать некое правило, что если ???, то класс должен считаться сервисом. В тех-же DI контейнерах имеются методы для регистрации сервисов и отдельно для регистрации экземпляров объектов (instance) - какая в этом случае разница?

Comment: `В тех-же DI контейнерах имеются методы для регистрации сервисов` можно пример?

Comment: Сервис - это предоставление своих услуг другим частям приложения. Данное понятие идет не из программирования, а из обихода. Парикмахерская, это тоже сервис по стрижке ваших волос, но вы можете говорить слово "сервис", а можете и не говорить. Можете назвать свои классы "BlaBlaBlaService", а можете не называть. Больше похоже на попытку привязать выбор обоев к среднегодовой температуре в Африке.

Comment: @tym32167 https://www.lightinject.net

Comment: @AlexKrass статические классы из System.IO тоже предоставляют свои услуги другим частям приложения, но никто их не называет сервисами.

Comment: @XelaNimed а если я назову вдруг свой класс, который обернет класс из IO и ничего не добавит нового, как ConsoleManagerService? То что вы будете делать? Опять же парикмахерскую никто в обиходе не называет сервисом, хотя это самый настоящий сервис. Ведь service в переводе означает обслуживание.

Comment: @XelaNimed но это так, ИМХО.

Comment: В теории есть разные подзоды. Кто то делит классы на классы с данными и классы с методами и называет методы сервисами. Кто то говорит, что если класс чисто функциональный и может/должен существовать в единственном экземпляре - то он тоже сервис. В контейнере там в принципе зарегистрированные классы называются сервисами. То есть однозначного ответа нет.

Comment: Это как с паттернами. Вот вы увидите код - вы можете сказать, является он паттерном или нет?

Comment: @AlexKrass цель вопроса не поиск аналогии сервиса из реального мира, а определение признаков, по которым можно однозначно сказать, что данный класс является сервисом. Понятно, что назвать его можно всяко разно, но ведь вопрос заключается не в названии файлов.

Comment: @XelaNimed тогда давайте проще, официально такого определения не существует ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Поэтому я в общем-то согласен с тем, что пишет tym32167.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно сервисом называют класс, который используется на всех уровнях приложения. Например сервис логирования, сервис аутентификации. Еще сервисом могут называть фасад какой то функциональности, типа сервис печати, сервис отправки писем. Сервисом могут называть запущенный отдельно код со своим ограниченным контекстом, типа Discovery Service, или сервис обмена валют.

Также есть другие подходы. Кто то делит классы на классы с данными и классы с методами и называет методы сервисами. Кто то говорит, что если класс чисто функциональный и может/должен существовать в единственном экземпляре - то он тоже сервис. В контейнере там в принципе зарегистрированные классы называются сервисами.

Сервис, как я думаю, широкое понятие. А класс - это весьма конкретное. Вы всегда можете понять, является ли обсуждаемый предмет классом. Но не всегда ясно, является ли он сервисом.
То есть однозначного ответа нет.